# Qlikview: tablebox or straight/pivot which would show minimum value and related value of the min value

Tags: indexing, min, qlikview

This is driving me nuts.
Say I have a mass of lists with product names, their prices and the origins of the pricing:
Product, 1$, USA
Product, 2€, EU
Product, 0.5€, HK

What is the correct table configuration to get this result, without duplicating the record of the same product name?:
Product 0.5€ HK

That is to say the table calculates the minimum price and shows the correct origin for the minimum price?

I either get all expanded pivot dupe products or the product origin is returned bogus.
Excel's pivot does not show duplicate rows, and the simple index and match functions work fast, but I want the two calculations to be done within Qlikview with success.

Please help,
-v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in the scripting portion of the app.

First you need to build a list of the Products and their minimum prices

```
 LOWEST_PRICES:
 Load Product_ID, 
      min(Selling_Price) as Min_Price
 resident SOURCE_TABLE
 group by Product_ID;
```

and then you are going to use that combination of the minimum price and the product_ID to join back source location onto the table

```
left join
Load Product_ID,
     Selling_Price as Min_Price,
     Source_Location
Resident SOURCE_TABLE;
```

Then you can just let QlikView associate to the Product_ID from the original table and it'll always return one Source_Location and one Min_Price

Comment: Let me get this straight - there's no way to do it purely within the program?
 Can it not look up values based on values it returns? So now we're basically giving the program the answers and manipulating the way it shows them - that's not exactly how I pictured it should work. Is this solution valid to at least give QV all the values, telling it to load minimum prices as a dimension and to present the data related to the id? My whole point is to not have to prepare any calculations outside of Qlikview. Sorry, I really want this just to be the least affected by extra calculations outside.

Comment: The scripting I suggested is within QlikView.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. But the minimum prices in this case need to be loaded from a document, is what you're saying, so they're not being calculated by Qlikview. Is there a way to just do tell qlikview of a reference value related to the minimum price? Like if I have the table show me min/max prices for the same product ID - to know what country had the min or max price? This method has me calculating it outside of qlikview and then just loading the data, which I could do much easier, it seems. I could be wrong, but I'm not understanding you fully.

Comment: Ok, I tried your method exactly. There's ~9K mistakes from 56K lines. So almost one fifth of information related to price origin is incorrect. What might be the cause?

Comment: Ok, scratch that last comment - it actually gave the correct values upon further scrutiny. I'm amazed that the index(match) in excel failed so miserably. I wish I knew what causes the error.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to also show the max price andd its origin within the same script? The minimum part is A-OK now.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone thinking of a solution - here's a ***modified version*** (**major credit goes to TheBudac**) to actually get more than what I was asking in the first place. This is a step up in actually giving me the minimum as well as the maximum pricing and both of the origins of the prices in question; *modifying the left join ORIGIN field to become unique was the key to actually get more than one answer from my data*; ENJOY!:

**

```
LOWESTPRICES:
LOAD EAN,
     min(PRICE) as MINEUR
resident ALL
group by EAN;
left join
LOAD EAN,
     PRICE as MINEUR,
     ORIGIN as MINORIGIN
Resident ALL;
HIGHESTPRICES:
LOAD EAN,
     max(PRICE) as MAXEUR
resident ALL
group by EAN;
left join
LOAD EAN,
     PRICE as MAXEUR,
     ORIGIN as MAXORIGIN
resident ALL;
//BRAND AND NAMES
LOAD EAN,
     ESSBRAND,
     ESSNAME
```

**

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your data in a structure like this:

```
PRODUCTS_TABLE
-description
-price
-id_origin (FK)

ORIGINS_TABLE
-id
-country
```

id and id_origin are linked (FK is foreign key, id is the primary key).
Your initial data should be splitted and fit into this kind of structure.
Then you should easily build your pivot.

Comment: Hi, I don't quite follow - the "country" is an id in itself in my case. So adding a fake fk foreign key id will make the product table find the -country- correctly by linking to a different table (origins_table) with an id too, is what you're saying? But the calculated minimum price (by expression) should be the linking value for the program to lookup the country, would it not? How will the logic work?

Comment: I usually prefer surrogated keys (id as integer). If you take country as key, so id_origin is substituted with "country". Once you set the domain model you can start building report on it.

Comment: I'm not that well versed in Qlikview, so I've no idea on building domain models yet. However my script file has multiple sources set to catch fields such as unique ids, names, brands, prices, origins, and since pivot tables show me nulls when asking for values - I've created within the same script another document link, which has the unique ids matched with names, brands. etc. But even though QV lets me get minimum prices next to my ids+names, the origin for that exact minimum price would show nulls or blanks, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around your suggestion. Sorry - I'm slow.

Comment: Ok, I went through my thoughts now and let me know if I'm correct in my actions: I named the origin columns in both lists be the same (the origin field is now shown as a key dimension); and now what I think is happening is: the name and id of all of my lists is connected, hence no nulls on names, expressions such as min(PRICE) show me the min values for the products and the origin expression is now showing the correct country code for each of the minimum prices returned by the previous expression. So did I succeed?