# How does Qlikview logic work with NULLs?

Tags: null, qlikview

I've found that Qlikview, after completing resident load from multiple values, returns null instead of a minimum/maximum value if there is more than one matching value within a dimension:

1. I have a list with names, origins, prices
2. I expect Qlikview to
   show me the minimum origin according to the minimum price (it does
   that - example:
   [Qlikview: tablebox or straight/pivot which would show minimum value and related value of the min value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307464/qlikview-tablebox-or-straight-pivot-which-would-show-minimum-value-and-related))
3. However, Qlikview returns NULL when trying to display a supplier,
   which is related to the origin

***How do I fix the null value problem?***

Any help appreciated :)

**UPDATE:**
The script is the same as the one in my link, with an added "Origin" field, to capture the cheapest origin of the product, and the most pricey one.
The problem is within the fact that if there is more than one entry with the same origin as minimum or maximum values in the straight table - it will not show the data.

Comment: Can you please post (if possible) data sample?

Comment: Am i right to assume that you have multiple origin/prices per name?

Comment: The script is the same as the one in my link, with an added "Origin" field, to capture the cheapest origin of the product, and the most pricey one.
The problem is within the fact that if there is more than one entry with the same origin as minimum or maximum values in the straight table - it will not show the data. // Sorry, no data sample, however easy to reproduce if you need to show minimum/maximum value related data, and there is more than one from say UK. So if the prices are (from the cheapest): UK, UK, IE, USA, USA - I will not be shown any minimum or maximum price country/suppliers.

Comment: please post data sample

Comment: Qlikview does not show a minimum value in the straight table even if the price is not identical and the supplier name is different IF the origin country is still the same. It must be because then there really ISN'T anything for the program to decide a minimum to. Unless this is a failure in logic on my end by sorting the script this way to first calculate a price, assign a minimum price country and on top of that assign the min/max price suppliers. I shall reverse the order and see if it works that way - which it should. // **EDIT: Nope, didn't do a thing to sort it another way... :(**

Comment: Here is an example of the data, because "Tatatrading is present not only in the lowest values - Qlikview does not explicitly calculate it to be the lowest price supplier in straight tables, although the pivot will show it (although pivot does not work for me because of duplication/line): |IT| TATATRADING |11.04
|IT| AVERSI |11.8|---
|IT| TATATRADING |12.08|---
|UK| MACH |13|---
|UK| MACH |15|---
|BG| BBPHARMA |22.28|---

Comment: I would suggest to add your script to your post, so that everyone can see what you are doing and where you made a mistake. Did you remember to add origin to the group by as well?

Comment: I figured out a solution with simple formulas. :) Posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone thinking of solutions for a similar problem - ***here is what worked for me***:

*First off:*
Qlikview is supposed to show nulls in my case, because there are multiple variants in the data for the program to choose from; with this in mind there is a formula to get all of the data to show (avoiding NULLs) and it is way easier than in the script view

*The formula(s):*

`firstsortedvalue(distinct origin, price, 1)` **this returned the origin with the lowest value**
`firstsortedvalue(distinct origin, -price, 1)` **this returned the origin with the highest value (notice the "-" minus sign in front of price);**

The distinct operator basically makes all of the values the program searches for to be displayed as uniques, therefore disregarding them as nulls.

***And that's that~!***